# Integer can not be written as a string with correct form to binary file

Tags: c#, binary-data

I'm reading data from a database to write to a binary file and using the `bcp` command of Sybase to write big data to my new database in one go (or thousand by thousand etc.)

You can see my entity `IdNumbers` are integer and I'm writing it to file as a string.

[image]

But in binary file data is like this:

> **f1**,LS-CIC,12,,1999-00-12,2070-00-01,1999-00-12,jdefinis,0,,N,0,0112,000,,0,,000,0,0,0, ,0,0,0, ,,,ALL
>   **d2**,LS-CIC,12,,1999-00-12,2070-00-01,1999-00-12,jdefinis,0,,N,0,0112,**,,0,,**,0,0,0, ,0,0,0, ,,,ALL
>   **d3**,LS-CIC,12,,1999-00-12,2070-00-01,1999-00-12,jdefinis,0,,N,0,0112,L1,,0,,L1,0,0,0, ,0,0,0, ,,,ALL
>   **d4**,LS-CIC,12,,1999-00-12,2070-00-01,1999-00-12,jdefinis,0,,N,0,0112,L2,,0,,L2,0,0,0, ,0,0,0, ,,,ALL
>   **d5**,LS-CIC,12,,1999-00-12,2070-00-01,1999-00-12,jdefinis,0,,N,0,0112,L3,,0,,L3,0,0,0, ,0,0,0, ,,,ALL

Each number "4" is converted to "d4" in binary file. Why? And how can I correct this problem?

Answer (score 0):

BinaryWriter puts some extra info about the data (such as length), into the file. If you want to write the file as text, use StreamWriter instead. See for ex,

```
using (var f = File.Create(filename))
{
    BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(f);
    bw.Write(String.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(0, 37)));
}
```

if you expect the output will be `0,1,.....,36`, No. It will be

`d0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36`

PS: `d` is 100 in ASCII which is the length of the string `0,1,...,36`

Answer (score 0):

I changed the BinaryWriter to StreamWriter for preventing the problem. In binary form always extra characters are coming with file as I4V says